# opencv mat CV_MAX_DIM in function setSize

Tags: opencv

I have a small OpenCV code:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

using namespace cv;

int
main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

  cv::Mat mask_img = cv::imread("image.png");
  cv::imshow("window",mask_img);

  return 0;
}
```

Yet when running I get the following error:

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (0 <= _dims && _dims <= CV_MAX_DIM) in
>   setSize, file /home/box/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line
>   88 terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
>   what():  /home/box/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp:88: error:
>   (-215) 0 <= _dims && _dims <= CV_MAX_DIM in function setSize
>
> Aborted

I'm using OpenCV 2.4.3 on kubuntu linux, compiled from source.

How can I resolve this error?

I solved it myself, just use

```
 g++ bla2.cpp `pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs` -o bla
```

Do not use your own linking libraries in addition like -lopencv_core etc

Answer (score -1):

Is your image read properly? Try adding these lines of code after `imread`: `if (image.empty()){ std::cerr << "Failed to read image" << std::endl; return 0;}`

Comment: This alone does not solve the problem, there are bigger issues at play.